# scan forwarded ports with OpenVAS/GVM?

Tags: firewalls, nmap, ports, openvas

I'm currently learning about network security and came across a problem, maybe I'm just missing something obvious but I'll try to explain my environment:

I have a Kali Linux VM connected to the WAN Interface (192.168.178.109) of a Pfsense VM, the PFsense has another LAN (.2.1) and DMZ (.1.1) interfaces with a few VMs connected to each Interface.
On the WAN Interface, I disabled all incoming traffic except some NAT rules for port forwarding to hosts in the DMZ (i hope i explained that correctly).

Now, if i run `nmap -sV –open –reason PFSENSE_WAN_INTERFACE` on my Kali VM it successfully scans the forwarded ports and shows the services in the DMZ:

| PORT | STATE | SERVICE | REASON | VERSION |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 21/tcp | Open | ftp | Syn-ack ttl 127 | Microsoft ftpd |
| 25/tcp | Open | Smtp | Syn-ack ttl 63 | Postfix smtpd |
| 53/tcp | Open | Domain | Syn-ack ttl 64 | (generic Dns response: REFUSED) |
| 80/tcp | Open | http | Syn-ack ttl 63 | Apache httpd 2.4.46 ((Ubuntu)) |
| 444/tcp | open | https | Syn-ack ttl 64 | Nginx (Pfsense) |

But if i try to do a vulnerability scan with GVM, it doesn't find anything. When I enable the allow any rule on the WAN Interface, the scan shows results, but i don't want to have the interface open.
Are there some settings in GVM I am missing? Am I doing it completely wrong?

Here is a Screenshot of the firewall settings of the WAN interface:
[image]

Here is a Screenshot of the GVM task:
[image]

Here is a Screenshot of the GVM task report:
[image]

Some advice would be gladly appreciated, and if neccessary, i can provide more information.

Comment: What are you seeing in the PFSense logs? You should see some IDS\IPS activity. If the IDS is working it will block the scan and cause faulty results.

Comment: thanks for the reply, but i dont have any IDS/IPS running on my pfsense.

Comment: Maybe you should...

Comment: yes, this is planned to be my next step in experimenting with pfsense.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default, OpenVAS will ping before it scans and it will ignore any system that doesn't respond to ping. This is to speed up the scan and avoid doing a full scan on a dead port.

Edit your scan target and change the `Alive Test` to `Consider Alive`. This tells OpenVAS that you always want to scan this target, even if it doesn't respond to ping.

This is the page where you change the Alive Test setting:

[image]

Comment: thank you! changing to "consider alive" helped and now i get results from the GVM scan. I already figured out that it must have something to do with pinging the WAN interface because I couldnt ping it from other machines in the same network. When I set up a rule on the WAN interface to allow pings the GVM scan suddenly worked, but changing the scan target is a more convenient solution for me. Again, thank you!